# Can't import watson conversation entities, why ?

Tags: csv, watson, watson-conversation

I got an issue with watson conversation, I am trying to import entities from csv files but it gives me a very VERY explicit error :[image]

On the right you can see my csv file.
If anyone had  a solution I would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Ok it is and encoding problem I had to convert my csv into utf-8 without BOM